# Vue 3 input type "range" mouse drag freezes shows "not-allowed" cursor

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, v-model

I am experiencing a bug in Vue 3 with an html `<input type="range">` element when `v-model` is used to bind a piece of state.

It doesn't happen all of the time, but after clicking and dragging the slider input eventually there will come a time when the dragging the handle of the range slider stops working and the mouse cursor becomes a "banned" icon similar to the `cursor: not-allowed` circle with a line through it. Using Chrome on Windows 10.

I have been able to reproduce it in two different Vue apps. One that uses the options API and another that uses the composition API.

Example code:

```
//app.js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input type="range" v-model="range" />

    {{ range }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      range: "5",
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Any work arounds? Solutions to this?

**Edit:**

Evidently it does not have to be in Vue to get this behavior. In the snippet below one can observe it if you click and drag the mouse in the area around the range slider a couple times - as if to highlight it, as one would highlight a line of text for example. After it becomes "highlighted" (though there is no visual indication of this) it ceases to be useable and you get the error-icon cursor on attempting to set new value by drag.

```html
<input type="range">
```

Comment: might be related to something else. Seems fine in isolation https://jsfiddle.net/fqhgsamt/2/

Comment: After testing on your fiddle i was able to reproduce it and I have a theory about the cause. I think in the course of trying to grab the handle if I miss and instead end up selecting or highlighting the range selector (as one would highlight a word or character in the browser) that's when it breaks. It is invisible, but I am pretty sure it is selected. Thinking that it might be trying activate the browser drag event. To reproduce, "draw" an invisible box around the range selector with mouse button pressed and then try to drag handle.

Comment: @Daniel you seem to be right that it's not related to Vue. I can get the same behavior in a vanilla HTML context.

Comment: chrome extension‍♂️?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further testing it turns out that this bug had nothing to do with vue and instead is present on all `<input type="range">` html elements in Chrome.

I devised a work-around that avoids the bad behavior.

```
//app.js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input type="range" v-model="range" @mousedown="removeRanges" />

    {{ range }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      range: "5",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    removeRanges() {
      window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```